# python regular expression: re.findall(r"(do|re|mi)+","mimi rere midore")

Tags: python, regex

I couldn't understand why this regular expression,

```
re.findall(r"(do|re|mi)+","mimi rere midore"),
```

generates this result,

```
['mi', 're', 're'].
```

My expected result is ['mimi', 'rere', 'midore']...

However, when I use this regular expression,

```
re.findall(r"(?:do|re|mi)+","mimi rere midore"),
```

it generates the result as expected.

Can you tell me the different between two regular expressions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is in the capturing group. With a capturing froup, `findall()` returns *only* what was captured. Without a capturing group, the whole match is returned.

In your first example, the group *only* captures the two characters, repeated or not. In the second example, the whole match includes any repetitions.

The [`re.findall()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) is quite clear on the difference:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. […] If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

If your `(do|re|mi)+` pattern is part of a larger pattern and you want `findall()` to *only* return the full repeated set of characters, use a non-capturing group for the two-letter options with a capturing group around the whole:

```
r'Some example text: ((?:do|re|me)+)'
```