# Python regex alternation

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find all links on a webpage in the form of `"http://something"` or `https://something.` I made a regex and it works:

```
L = re.findall(r"http://[^/\"]+/|https://[^/\"]+/", site_str)
```

But, is there a shorter way to write this? I'm repeating ://[^/\"]+/ twice, probably without any need. I tried various stuff, but it doesn't work. I tried:

```
L = re.findall(r"http|https(://[^/\"]+/)", site_str)
L = re.findall(r"(http|https)://[^/\"]+/", site_str)
L = re.findall(r"(http|https)(://[^/\"]+/)", site_str)
```

It's obvious I'm missing something here or I just don't understand python regexes enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using capturing groups, and [`.findall()` alters behaviour when you use those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547033/python-regular-expression-re-findallrdoremi-mimi-rere-midore/15547065#15547065) (it'll only return the contents of capturing groups). Your regex can be simplified, but your versions will work if you use *non*-capturing groups instead:

```
L = re.findall(r"(?:http|https)://[^/\"]+/", site_str)
```

You don't need to escape the double quote if you use single quotes around the expression, and you only need to vary the `s` in the expression, so `s?` would work too:

```
L = re.findall(r'https?://[^/"]+/', site_str)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> example = '''
... "http://someserver.com/"
... "https://anotherserver.com/with/path"
... '''
>>> re.findall(r'https?://[^/"]+/', example)
['http://someserver.com/', 'https://anotherserver.com/']
```

Comment: It *feels* as if the `?` mark is for '(https)'... I learned something new.

Comment: @Elazar: It applies to the atom preceding it; you'd have to group the whole `https` part for the question mark to apply to more than just one character. `?` has the same scope as `*`, if that helps understand this better.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thank you. I didn't even know about capturing groups.