# Python regex similar expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with two different types of data I'd like to parse with a regex; however, the data is similar enough that I can't find the correct way to distinguish it.

Some lines in my file are of form:

```
AED=FRI
AFN=FRI:SAT
AMD=SUN:SAT
```

Other lines are of form

```
AED=20180823
AMD=20150914
AMD=20150921
```

The remaining lines are headers and I'd like to discard them.  For example

```
[HEADER: BUSINESS DATE=20160831]
```

My solution attempt so far is to match first three capital letters and an equal sign,

```
r'\b[A-Z]{3}=\b'
```

but after that I'm not sure how to distinguish between dates (eg 20180823) and days (eg FRI:SAT:SUN).

The results I'd expect from these parsing functions:

```
Regex weekday_rx = new Regex(<EXPRESSION FOR TYPES LIKE AED=FRI>);
Regex date_rx = new Regex(<EXPRESSION FOR TYPES LIKE AED=20160816>);


weekdays = [weekday_rx.Match(line) for line in infile.read()]
dates = [date_rx.Match(line) for line in infile.read()]
```

Comment: Could you clarify what result you expect?

Comment: Also, are you processing the multiline string (the whole file) or read it line by line?

Comment: line by line most likely

Comment: Oh, C#+Python like pseudo code :)

Comment: ya, sorry about that

Comment: Have you tried regex alternation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875404/python-regex-alternation

Comment: See https://ideone.com/kqHfqV

Comment: Thanks, ideone let's you post runnable snippets?

Comment: Yes, it is an online IDE supporting many languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r'\S*\d$'
```

Will match all non-whitespace characters that end in a digit

Will match `AED=20180823`

```
r'\S*[a-zA-Z]$'
```

Matches all non-whitespace characters that end in a letter.

will match `AED=AED=FRI`
`AFN=FRI:SAT`
`AMD=SUN:SAT`

Neither will  match

`[HEADER: BUSINESS DATE=20160831]`

This will match both

```
r'(\S*[a-zA-Z]$|\S*\d$)'
```

Replacing the * with the number of occurences you expect will be safer, the `(a|b)` is match a or match b

Comment: Thank you  The $ at the end means use as many characters as the line contains?

Comment: No it means ends with: "Matches the end of string"

Comment: So the first regex you posted would read as "Match all repetiions of captial letters, and string must end with a digit"?

Comment: I think it should be noted that the patterns will work with `re.match` only. Perhaps, they will work with `re.search`, but I understand it so that the `XXX=123453` are independent strings.

Comment: Could the last regex you provided be shortened to `r'\S*([a-zA-Z]|\d)$'`, or even `r'\S*[a-zA-Z0-9]$'`?

Comment: Yes, that would be more succinct, but perhaps harder to read for the OP?

Comment: Yes, keep it dumb and explicit for me plz haha

Answer (score 2):

The following is a solution in Python :)

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'\b([A-Z]{3})=((\d)+|([A-Z])+)')

str_test_01 = "AMD=SUN:SAT"
m = p.search(str_test_01)
print (m.group(1))
print (m.group(2))


str_test_02 = "AMD=20150921"
m = p.search(str_test_02)
print (m.group(1))
print (m.group(2))

"""
<Output>
AMD
SUN
AMD
20150921
"""
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: I hope it will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Use pipes to express alternatives in regex. Pattern '[A-Z]{3}:[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{3}' will match both ABC and ABC:ABC. Then use parenthesis to group results:

```
import re

match = re.match(r'([A-Z]{3}:[A-Z]{3})|([A-Z]{3})', 'ABC:ABC')
assert match.groups() == ('ABC:ABC', None)

match = re.match(r'([A-Z]{3}:[A-Z]{3})|([A-Z]{3})', 'ABC')
assert match.groups() == (None, 'ABC')
```

You can research the concept of named groups to make this even more readable. Also, take a look at the docs for the match object for useful info and methods.

Comment: Thanks, upvoting for an alternate approach